# Get post type from taxonomy or category page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives

This might be somewhat backward, but how can one get the post type being displayed on an archive page? Alternatively, how can one get the post type associated with a given taxonomy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get_queried_object()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) is your friend. It will tell you all kinds of information about what your template files are trying to do. From within, you can discover your post type. Try doing a `var_dump` to take a look at that object.

As for your second question, taxonomy is not, as far as I know, isolated to one post_type, so that is not really something one can assume. For example, "location" may be a taxonomy to both post types: "Restaurants" and "Grocery Stores".

Comment: This does not work on `is_tax('my_custom_taxonomy');`  I need to get the custom post type of a custom taxonomy, thought this would help, but this does not.  This does not return the post type of that taxonomy.